# python dictionary : values and keys

Tags: python, dictionary

so i have python homework and had to print values and keys, but with "->" between them.

```
d = {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30}
```

this is values and keys and had to print it like this

```
x -> 10
y -> 20
z -> 30
```

i tried to do it like this

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key + "->" + value)
```

but it tells me that "an only concatenate list (not "str") to list"
what can i do?

Comment: Did you mean: `print(f'{key} -> {value}')`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: replace `+` with `,`

```
print(key, "->", value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str` *constructor*.

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key + "->" + str(value))
                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Another approach could be using *string* interpolation.

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(f'{key} -> {value}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `format`

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print("{}->{}".format(key, value))
```

You can also solve this problem in one line:

```py
print('\n'.join(["{}->{}".format(key, value) for key, value in d.items()]))
```

Result:

```py
x->10
y->20
z->30
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "items" method in the dictionary class:

```
for i,v in d.items():
    print(i, '->', v)
```

Make sure you're using a comma (,) and not a plus sign (+) between the variables of your one row.